# R - Create biosequence from a list of sequences with sample()

Tags: r, sample

I have a list of biosequences that are very similar. Firstly I want to create a distance matrix NxN and then I want to generate another sequence with sample() that will be also quite similar to the others but not identical. I try to create the sequence by using the sample fucntion but it returns a copy of my initial list. Lastly, I want to update the matrix to contain the distances of the generated sequence. Is there a way to simply bind the new distances or I need to create a new one?

```
sequences <- read.fasta('/media/losve/Νέος τόμος/Scripts/bnp54/ergasia 2/histone4.fa')
seqnames <- c("human", "mouse", "fly", "plant", "cow", "worm", "chick", "rat","yeast", "frog")
myseqs <- list() 
for(i in 1:length(sequences))
{
  myseqs[i] = toupper(paste(sequences[[i]], collapse=''))
}

names(myseqs) <- seqnames
dist_matrix <- matrix(, nrow = length(sequences), ncol = length(sequences))

for(i in 1:length(sequences))
{
  for(j in 1:length(sequences))
  {
  dist_matrix[i][j] <- pairwiseAlignment(myseqs[i], myseqs[j], substitutionMatrix = "BLOSUM50")
  }
}

new_sequence <- sample(myseqs, replace = TRUE )
```

Answer (score 0):

`sample` just draws elements from a vector without replacement by default. It is not intended to modify the elements in any way. It just takes a random subset of your data if n < total observations. For n = total observations, it has to return the exact input but just in a different order.

## Introducing sequencing errors

You should consider shell tools to introduce random mutation errors in genomic sequences, e.g. Grinder, Mason or SiMSeq.

## Getting a permutation for each sequence

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1337)

list("AATTGG", "GGCCGG") %>%
  map_chr(~ {
    .x %>%
      str_split(pattern = "") %>%
      simplify() %>%
      sample() %>%
      paste0(collapse = "")
  })
#> [1] "ATGATG" "CCGGGG"
```

Comment: I don't want to add mutation errors, I want to create a new sequence with the same elements but not in the exact same order. So that there will be some distance between them.

Comment: @Greggs I revised my answer

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you very much!